# Finding rows and columns with the maximum number of 1s in a randomly generated binary matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

The output of this program works fine. But there's one thing I've not been able to implement. In some cases, I don't have a row or column with the highest number of 1s. Sometimes I have 2 or more rows/columns which have the same "HIGHEST" number of ones. But my program only returns 1 row/column.

I want a case whereby If i have more than 2 rows/columns with the same highest number of 1s. Both rows will be displayed. e.g. "Row(s) with the most 1's: 1,2" or if it's a column it can say "Row(s) with the most 1's: 1,2".

Please I need help with this. I'm stuck.

```
import java.util.Random; 
    import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class LargestRowColumn 
    { 
       // declare a 2 dimensional array or an array of arrays 
       private static int[][] randArray; 

       public static void main(String[] args) 
       { 
        do
        {
          // Create a scanner to get Input from user. 
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
          System.out.print("\nEnter the array size n:"); 
          int rows = scanner.nextInt(); 
          int cols = rows;

          randArray = new int[rows][cols]; 

          // loop through the number of rows in thw array 
          for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) 
          { 
             // loop through the elements of the first array in the array 
             for (int j = 0; j < randArray[0].length; j++) 
             { 
                // set a random int 0-1 to the array 
                randArray[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 1); 
                // print the number just assigned 
                System.out.print(randArray[i][j]); 
             }
             // make a linebreak each row. 
             System.out.println();
          }
          System.out.print("Row(s) with the most 1's: " + scanRow(randArray) + "\n");
          System.out.print("Columns(s) with the most 1's: " + scanColumn(randArray) + "\n"); 
        }
        while(true);   
       } 

       // quick method I made to get a random int with a min and max 
       public static int getRandomInt(int min, int max) 
       { 
          Random rand = new Random(); 
          return rand.nextInt(max-min+1)+min; 
       }


       public static int scanRow(int[][] array) 
       {
          int result = -1;
          int highest = -1;

          for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)// Here we are about start looping through the matrix values
          {
             int temp = 0; // Setting the first index to 0.
             for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)// 
             {
                //Assign current location to temporary variable
                temp = temp + array[row][col];
             }

             if (temp > highest)
             {
                highest = temp;
                result = row + 1;
             }
          }
          return result;
       } // end of row method

       private static int scanColumn(int[][] array) 
       {
            int result = -1;
            int highest = -1;

            // declare and initialize the variable(here you've 'created' it, to then call it on if statement)
            int col = 0;

            for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
            {
                int temp = 0;
                //declare the variable in the for loop
                for (col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) 
                {
                    //Assign current location to temp variable
                    temp = temp + array[row][col];
                }

               if (temp > highest) 
               {
                   highest = temp;
                 result = col;
               }
            }
            return result;
       }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach, first thing why do you need to loop all over the 2D array again , u can figure out the highest 1's in rows and columns while inserting them and insert them in an array ( array of rows and array for columns) the carry will be of custom type which is a class with two parameters , score(which is number of 1's) and index( which is the number of the row or column), then sort the arrays and print the indexes related to top scores.

if you are expecting to receive the array with the inputs you can do the same but with new loop.

so your insert loop will be like this

```
       List<Wrapper> rowsList = new ArrayList<Wrapper>(rows);
        List<Wrapper> colsList = new ArrayList<Wrapper>(cols);
         for(int i=0;i<cols;i++) {
             colsList.add(new Wrapper(i,0));
         } 
      // loop through the number of rows in thw array 
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
      { 
         int sum =0;
         // loop through the elements of the first array in the array 
         for (int j = 0; j < cols j++) 
         { 

            // set a random int 0-1 to the array 
            randArray[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 1); 
            // print the number just assigned 
            System.out.print(randArray[i][j]); 
            sum+=randArray[i][j];//add for row
             colsList.get(j).setScore(colsList(j).getScore() +randArray[i][j]);//add for column
         }
          rowsList.add(new Wrapper(i,sum));
         // make a linebreak each row. 

      }

     Collections.sort(rowsList,new Comparator<Wrapper>() {

              @Override
              public int compare(Wrapper obj1,Wrapper obj2) {
                   if(obj1.getScore() > obj2.getScore())
                      return -1;
                    if(obj1.getScore() < obj2.getScore())
                      return 1;
                  return 0;
             }
        });
        if(rowsList.isEmpty())
           return -1;
        int max = rowsList.get(0).getScore();
         for(Wrapper obj:rowsList) {
            if(obj.getScore()< max)
              break;
             System.out.println(obj.getIndex);
          }
         //DO THE SAME FOR COLUMNS
```

your wrapper class will be

```
          public class Wrapper {
                 private int index;
                 private int score;

                 public Wrapper(int index,int score) {
                       this.index = index;
                        this.score = score;
                 }

                 public int getIndex() {
                       return this.index;
                 }

                 public int getScore() {
                      return this.score;
                  }

                 public void setScore(int score) {
                       this.score = score
                  }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is in keeping with the OP use of arrays.

Instead of returning an `int`, which would be one row, you can return `int[]`.

Personally, I would init the `int[]` to the number of rows in the array, because what if every row has the same number of 1's?

```
int[] results = new int[array[0].length];
```

Then, instead of adding in the rows, I would have a variable used to designate which spot to add the row to, i.e., `results[0]` etc.

```
int index = 0;
```

Then, all it takes is a small adjustment to how you add your results to the array.

```
public static int[] scanRow(int[][] array) 
       {
          int highest = -1;
          int index = 0; //ADD HERE
          int[] results = new int[array[0].length]; //ADD HERE

            ... //Your code here

             if (temp > highest)
             {
                highest = temp;
                //CLEAR THE RESULT LIST
                for(int x = 0; x < results.length; x++){
                    results[x] = -1;
                }
                index = 0; //RESET THE INDEX
                results[index] = row + 1;
                index ++;
             } else if (temp == highest{
                highest = temp;
                results[index] = row + 1;
                index ++;
             }
          }
          return results;
       } // end of row method
```

> Personally, I would use an ArrayList for these types of things, so heres how I would do it using it.

I would make the return type of the method an `ArrayList<int>`.

```
public static ArrayList<int> scanRow(int[][] array)
```

Then declare my `ArrayList<int>`

```
ArrayList<int> results = new ArrayList<>();
```

and the if statements are a little easier to handle, since `ArrayList` as a `clear()` and `add()` method.

```
if (temp > highest)
{
    highest = temp;
    //CLEAR THE RESULT LIST
    results.clear();
    results.add(row+1);
} else if (temp == highest{
    highest = temp;
    results.add(row + 1);
}
```

> EDIT
>   Don't forget to edit your print statements accordingly.